# Converting a lookup over a week to a month?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a lookup that gets and groups results on a weekly basis:

```
SELECT
COUNT(IF(YEARWEEK(Submitted, 1) = YEARWEEK(NOW(), 1), 1, null)) AS Bookings,
COUNT(IF(YEARWEEK(Submitted, 1) = YEARWEEK(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 WEEK, 1), 1, null)) AS LastWeekBookings
FROM Bookings
```

Is there a month alternative to YEARWEEK that can get the year and month and previous month to count the bookings over a month instead?

Comment: `YEAR(Submitted) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(Submitted) = MONTH(NOW())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`LAST_DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) to determine the current or the previous month:

```
SELECT
  SUM(LAST_DAY(Submitted) = LAST_DAY(NOW()) AS Bookings,
  SUM(LAST_DAY(Submitted) = LAST_DAY(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS LastMonthBookings
FROM Bookings
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer as I assume when the year changes it won't mess up, whereas comparing the month and year separately, when you get to January, removing a month from January will look for results from December in the same year?

Comment: @BN83 both answers do not mess up the dates.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I missed the part where it took a month off the year, assuming that removes a year too if it's January.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple function that combines year and month the way `YEARWEEK()` combines year and week. So just compare both separately. And subtract `INTERVAL 1 MONTH` instead of `INTERVAL 1 WEEK`.

```
SELECT
COUNT(IF(YEAR(Submitted) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(Submitted) = MONTH(NOW()), 1, null)) AS Bookings,
COUNT(IF(YEAR(Submitted) = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(Submitted) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 1, null)) AS LastMonthBookings
FROM Bookings
```